# How to Add Animation to Translated Box in Merged Table Column on Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, html-table

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/5sb7ymt0/1/) and let me know how I can add animation to the `#map` to always see it on view port while the table is in the view port? (some thing like sticky notes)

As you can see the position of the `#map` is hard coded in `-100px` at:

```css
transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, -30px);
```

but what I need to do is keeping the `#map` in view port until the table still presenting on scroll down or up

```js
$(function() {
  
});
```

```css
@import url("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css");
#map {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: rotate(-90deg) translate(-100px, -30px);
  color: #ed217c;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="height:300px; background:yellow">Scrool Drown Please</div>
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="28"><span id="map">New Users</span></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>  <tr>
    <td>555 77 855</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<div style="height:300px;background:yellow"">Scroll Up Please</div>
```

Comment: So you want it fixed on the screen while the table is visible?

Answer (score 1):

Use $(window).scroll(callback)
I updated some line 
jsfiddle.net/5sb7ymt0/2/

Comment: Phuong Vu Thanks for reply but the only problem is this is not really animating the `#map` and it comes out of table on scrooll down!